# how to Parameterized States id in Spring Webflow 2

Tags: java, spring-webflow

I'm trying to dynamicaly change my state id, taking it from the getter method of my external class like this:

```
<transition on="confermAction" to="testAction">
    <set name="flashScope.arrivalFlowId" value="ExternalClass.getParam()" />
    <evaluate expression="visibilitaCBean.confermaVisibilita(selezioneVisibilitaBBean)" />
</transition>

<action-state id="testAction">
    <evaluate expression="ExternalClass.testAction()"></evaluate>
    <transition on="yes" to="'${flashScope.arrivalFlowId}'" />
    <transition on="no" to="Current_Flow"/>
</action-state>
```

On `confermAction` action I set my id in `flashScope` of the current flow correctly. But when I try to set it as a state id with `${flashScope.arrivalFlowId}` it doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does `confermAction` need to be `confirmAction`, or does the spelling not matter in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

As Spring Webflow evolved, [EL used also changed](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/webflow/2.4.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/#el-language-choices) as:

```
    Spring webflow  version#           Expression Language Used
            1                               OGNL
            2.0                             Unified EL
            >= 2.1                          Spring EL
```

As part of this upgrade/change, for SWF version > 2.0, expressions with ${} in flow definitions must be changed to #{}.

As ${} is not working for you, it prompts me to believe you are using Spring webflow version > 2.0.

So try by changing transition in your testAction state to:

```
    <transition on="yes" to="#{flashScope.arrivalFlowId}"/>
```

Comment: as Prasad Suggested i replace ${} whith #{} and it works! thank you Prasad